# iOS streaming video from Spring MVC

Tags: java, ios, spring, cocoa-touch, spring-mvc

I'm writing both server and client side application that should stream video from server written using Spring MVC to iOS application that plays it using MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Obstacle is: MPMoviePlayerViewController always shows _itemFailedToPlayToEnd error. I've tried many different solutions but still no success. If I download video first and then play it from filesystem - everything goes fine.

This is my iOS code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myhost.com:8080/application/files/1];
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
[self.moviePlayerController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerController];
```

And here goes my Java code:

```
OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
httpServletResponse.setContentType(file.getContentType());
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getFilePath());
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
out.flush();
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: What happens when you point a browser to the URL?  Is the Content-Type being set correctly?  What are the requirements to using MPMoviePlayerViewController?  Does it handle streaming from what looks like a basic file download, or do you have to do something different/special?

Comment: In browser it simply downloads a file. I've tried different Content-Types for application result is still the same but browser changes its behavior from downloading file to launching quicktime player in it.
AS I understand MPMoviePlayerViewController could handle octet-stream or video/* Content-Types depends on settings which I tried all. 
Yup I want basic partial file download with progressive playing.

Comment: Change the "Accepts" header in your client to `*/*` and see if that helps.

Comment: I can't change Accepts header in client 'cos framework incapsulates it.

Comment: Can you print them on the server-side?